# Rider - Adding libraries to 'Add Reference' window

Tags: rider

I'm creating some class libraries to share code between projects and each library requires references to external libraries. So far the only way I've found to add these libraries is using the 'Add From...' button in the 'Add Reference' window.

[image: Add Reference window]

Is there a way to add my libraries to the list in the window so they can be found by using the search bar?

Or is there another way to quickly add a bunch of libraries as reference?

Comment: Maybe you need add all your projects into the one solution and use project references?

Comment: That would be fine, except that it would be nice if you could just reference Unity libraries from the installation folder so they will be updated when a new version is installed. Right now that means traversing the folder structure which takes a little while each time and then manually selecting the correct dlls. Also it's preferable to me to have separate folders per library

Comment: You mean there is no unity libs in the list? And you have to look for them somewhere in the system?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've done it manually by now and it wasn't that bad in hindsight. But it was just terribly frustrating that there is no shortcut at all. Not even editing some list in a file somewhere.

Comment: Are your interested specifically in UnityEngine and UnityEditor or any others?

Comment: If it could remember the libraries in the Unity folder that would save a lot of clicks until some other settings are added

Answer (score 1):

It is the very good feature we try to add it. Please issue our issue tracker to track progress or voting: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/RIDER-12756

Comment: Was this added?

Comment: Yes, it added into Rider few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt seem to be possible from the GUI but you can do it by editing
the .csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Reference Include="MyLib">
      <HintPath>/path/to/your/lib/MyLib.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```